# Civix reports "Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php"

Tags: drupal, api, extension, developer, civix

I used the command `civix generate:api Civicrmzapier submit` to an API function to an extension i am working on, but got the following error as on the screenshot and the api function is not added.

[image: Civix Error unable to find civicrm.settings.php file]

> Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php. By default, this tool searches the parent directories for a standard CMS (Drupal, WordPress, etal) and standard civicrm.settings.php. Symlinks and multisite configurations may interfere. To customize, set variable CIVICRM_SETTINGS to point to the preferred civicrm.settings.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `generate:api` subcommand (and a few others) require access to a working copy of CiviCRM.

To locate this, it uses a process reminiscent of `drush` or `wp-cli`. For example, if the command-line is running inside `/var/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.example.foo/`, then it will perform an upward search to find the CMS root:

```
/var/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.example.foo
/var/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext
/var/www/sites/default/files/civicrm
/var/www/sites/default/files
/var/www/sites/default
/var/www/sites
/var/www
/var
```

In each case, it is looking for a tell-tale sign of a CMS+Civi system. For example, in a typical Drupal installation, you'd expect to see the file `sites/default/civicrm.settings.php`.

There are some cases where the default search may not work correctly, e.g.

- Using a new or custom CMS.
- Using a multisite configuration.
- Using symlinks.

The quickest way to resolve this? Don't rely on a search. Instead, tell `civix` specifically where to find your copy of CiviCRM by setting the variable `CIVICRM_SETTINGS`, e.g.

```
export CIVICRM_SETTINGS=/var/www/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php
civix generate:api ...
```

More aggressive ways to resolve this would be:

- Arrange your directory structure so that it looks like a normal build (e.g. replace symlinks with real folders).
- Use [`civibuild`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/) for your dev sites. It always produces standard builds.
- Submit a patch for [`Civi/Cv/Bootstrap`](https://github.com/civicrm/cv/blob/master/src/Bootstrap.php) to add support for your directory structure.

Comment: Note sure if this answer is still true today? https://github.com/civicrm/cv/issues/130

Answer (score 0):

Note that civix does not generate/add anything because it can not find your civicrm.settings.php - that's a configuration issue

Can you e.g.

```
civix generate:api -h
```

Note the option that you can set an environment variable CIVICRM_SETTINGS pointing to where your civicrm.settings.php is - if needed.